# Data archiving solutions

Tags: database, hive, archive

I have an application set up using mysql at the backend with about 130 tables, total size is currently more than 30-40 GB and growing fast.

Our db is well optimized but we believe that due to the size of the database , the performance is taking a hit.

I need to implement a process to archive data, after a little reading i read that i could push all archivable data to hadoop , what i need to know is , is there any way by which i can directly hit hadoop to retrieve data from my backend (codeigniter,cakephp,django etc...) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try Apache Sqoop: http://sqoop.apache.org/

Sqoop 1 was originally designed for moving data from relational databases to Hadoop. Sqoop 2 is more ambitious and aims to move data between any two sources.

Comment: Thanks for your input

Comment: @frb: thanks. Sqoop2 is deprecated as of now. They recommend to use sqoop1 in production systems.